# Beta 17 definitions in conflict with jQuery definitions

Tags: typescript, angular, typescript-typings

I have an issue with definitions from jQuery and Angular2.

I have downloaded jQuery definitions using `typings`.

I have Angular2 with version of `2.0.0-beta.17`.

The behavior is that as soon as I've updated from `2.0.0-beta.15`, I got tons of typescript errors, such as:

> error TS2339: Property 'on' does not exist on type 'ElementFinder'.
>   error TS2339: Property 'hasClass' does not exist on type
>   'ElementFinder'. error TS2339: Property 'removeClass' does not exist
>   on type 'ElementFinder'. error TS2339: Property 'addClass' does not
>   exist on type 'ElementFinder'. error TS2339: Property 'removeClass'
>   does not exist on type 'ElementFinder'. error TS2339: Property 'find'
>   does not exist on type 'ElementFinder'.

and

> error TS2339: Property 'param' does not exist on type 'cssSelectorHelper'.

Now, I've also realized, that there is an issue with jQuery typings:

> error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same
>   type.  Variable '$' must be of type 'cssSelectorHelper', but here has
>   type 'JQueryStatic'.

which, as I understand, most likely causes all of the issues.

Has anyone else encountered this issue, and managed to solve it?

My definitions that I use:

```
node_modules/angular2/ts/typings/tsd.d.ts
typings/index.d.ts
```

Where `typings/index.d.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="globals/bootstrap/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/jquery/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/lodash/index.d.ts" />
```